# How can I have the Google+ style hovercard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus

I really like the Google+ style hovercard. When you hover over a profile picture, it pops up a little box, similar to the "established users" hovercards here on Stack Overflow.

[image: Google+ Hover-card]

I know how to do the CSS, but the JavaScript is what I need help with.

I have a code here that is somewhat like it: http://jsfiddle.net/NathanJohnson/AhVQN/ But, it doesn't work that good. The mouse offset does not work correctly.

Could someone help me with getting this working properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what don't you like about it? it seems to work fairly well for me (on a mac in ff)

Comment: @Landon It is too far from the cursor. I want it to be closer, so it is easier to put your cursor onto the box without it going away. And it would look better closer to the cursor, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the mouse offset in this section:

```
  var pos = {
        // or you could position it relative to the mouse
        top: (e.clientY + 2) + 'px',
        left: (e.clientX + 2) + 'px'
    };
```

Change the `e.clientY + 2` to `e.clientY + 1` and the hovercard will be closer to the cursor.

Comment: I actually found out the problem. There was padding so right when you hovered over the edge it would pop up and then it didn't look right. It is much better now, and along the way I added a better animation: http://jsfiddle.net/NathanJohnson/AhVQN/ Thanks for your answer.

Comment: But, I'm wondering, how can I make it where when you hover it will pop up right by the mouse. Like on Google+, it doesn't just pop up at the edge of the image where you rolled your mouse over, it pops up right next to the mouse. Is there a way to do this with jQuery?

Comment: have you tried setting `top: e.clientY + 'px, left: e.clientX + 'px'`? That will make it appear right next to the cursor. You may want to try shortening the `show` time so that it appears a little faster - that will help it show up closer to the cursor if you keep moving it after the mouseover is triggered.

Comment: Yeah. I wonder how Google does it. Well, they are Google and they make it a pain in the butt to find their JavaScript. (maybe not on Google+, but on Gmail they do) I wish it could be closer to the mouse instead of at the edge. I increased the time and it still does it. Maybe there is a different method? Would `.hover()` work the same?

Comment: Actually I just thought of something... is there  away to just make it pop up next to the image? Similar to [my Get Satisfaction profile](http://forum.yola.com/people/nathanieljohnson), hover over my profile image to see. This would be a lot easier. When I got that code it did have something about `$(this).offset()` (something like that) but I don't know how to use it.